# Приложения или нет?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> На экране телевизора я увидел ван Бастена, лучшего игрока Европы конца 80-х.
>   На экране телевизора я увидел ван Бастена, в конце 80-х — лучшего игрока Европы.

После запятых это обособленные приложения? Корректен ли второй пример? Нужно ли тире во втором примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, наиболее правильно назвать данную конструкцию уточняющим оборотом. Чтобы себя проверить, необходимо попробовать задать к спорной части вопрос "кто именно?", при этом мысленно оценивая смысловую возможность такого ответа, как "лучший игрок Европы восьмидесятых годов". Если никаких **смысловых**  нестыковок не возникает, то есть, например, отсутствия пояснительного характера сочетания, то конструкция является уточнением. В ином же случае это обособленное приложение, однако также обращу внимание, что такой выбор строго зависит от контекста, поэтому некоторые случаи всё же могут быть оценены двояко. Сейчас поясню на примере:

“Дочь Светланы, **Анна Викторовна**, выглядела уставшей“. Здесь сочетание *Анна Викторовна* является уточнением и необходимо для более понятной трактовки своих мыслей. Если собеседник плохо осведомлён о семействе Светланы, то, вполне вероятно, будет в замешательстве и точно не поймёт, о ком идёт речь. Таким образом, уточняющий оборот внёс больше ясности в диалог.

“Михаил, **откровенный лгун**, собирался на новое дело“. В этом же случае *откровенный лгун* не вносит ясность в то, кем является Михаил, а просто характеризует его личность. Читатель, скорее всего, так никогда и не узнает, кем он работает, где живёт, его семейный статус и прочие вещи, **раскрывающие** личность и дающие полное понимание пооисходящего.

Надеюсь, с этой темой хоть как-то помог разобраться. Перейдём ко второму вопросу.  Здесь тире, как я считаю, не совсем уместно — следует заменить запятой, являющейся нормативной в подобных случаях, что обусловлено обособленным обстоятельством, которым и является сочетание "в конце восьмидесятых". Получим следующее:

“На экране телевизора я увидел ван Бастена, в конце 80-х, лучшего игрока Европы“.

Однако всё же его можно поставить как авторский знак, что, как мне кажется, укрепляется не совсем понятным видом предложения при постановке запятой. Становится непонятно, увидели ли Вы Бастена в конце восьмидесятых или он был лучшим игроком Европы в этот период. Но в таком случае я бы просто перестроил предложение:

“На экране телевизора я увидел ван Бастена, лучшего игрока Европы, в конце восьмидесятых“.

Надеюсь, что помог разобраться. Спасибо за интересный вопрос, кстати говоря.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. Корректна ли запись без знака? [Вот пример такой пунктуации](https://irecommend.ru/sites/default/files/imagecache/copyright1/user-images/269081/8l9H1X0pYkRGqHDWJ51flw.jpg).

Comment: В данном **заголовке СМИ** она корректна на основании особого оформления текстовых полей. Главное слово и приложение (а здесь, кстати, сочетание является именно приложением из-за, можно сказать, "повествовательного" стиля, описывающего все грани личности персоны) как бы разрываются, что необходимо для выделения важности каждого поля.

Comment: Кстати, на форуме уже задавался подобный вопрос, причём был объявлен конкрусным. Там я изложил совсем другую точку зрения, хотя сейчас ближе эта.